# error 1052: column 'LastName' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE VIEW CustomerInterestsView AS
    SELECT LastName AS CustomerLastName,
            C.FirstName AS CustomerFirstName,
            A.LastName AS ArtistName
    FROM
        CUSTOMER AS C
            JOIN
        CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT AS CAI ON C.CustomerID = CAI.CustomerID
            JOIN
        ARTIST AS A ON CAI.ArtistID = A.ArtistID;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `SELECT LastName` to `SELECT C.LastName`.

Both the `CUSTOMER` and `ARTIST` tables have a `LastName` column. It's not clear which of the two `LastName` columns you're referring to, thus "the `LastName` column is ambiguous".

By prefixing it with the table alias `C`, you're specifying that you want the `LastName` column *from the `CUSTOMERS` table*.